# java app working in IDE,same jar file not responding

Tags: java, classpath, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Ubuntu 11.10,jdk 1.7.I have created a desktop application which sends mail by checking the database. In netbeans 7.2.1 ,the application works fine with a bootstrap warning in IDE.But the jar build is not responding when double clicked.When the jar file was executed through the commandline in terminal,It shows No Class Found Exception javax.mail.Authenticator.Is setting the Classpath is my problem?
The code used to send mail.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Desk_mail
{



    private String from = "mailid";
    private String subject = "Test Mail";
    private String smtpServ = "smtp.gmail.com";

    DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
    Desk_mailPojo dmp ;



         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
       {
           try{
               int status;
               Desk_mail m1=new Desk_mail();
               status=m1.changestatus();
               if(status==1)
               {
                   System.out.println("Email sent succesfull");
               }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                 try{
                    Desk_mail m1=new Desk_mail();
                    String p=e.getMessage()+e.getStackTrace();
                     m1.sendmail(p, "mailid");
                }
                    catch(Exception en){
                        throw new Exception("changestatus" + en.getMessage());
                    }

              throw new Exception("main" + e.getMessage());
         }

        }
        public int changestatus() throws Exception
        {
            String status,email,body;
            String policyname,policyno;
            int remdays;
            int detailsid;
            Date remdate ;
            Date enddate;
            Date expdate;
            readxml rl= new readxml();
            dbcon.results = new ArrayList();
            try{
                Desk_mail m1=new Desk_mail();
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = new Date();
                System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
                dbcon.query="-----MYSQL QUERY----- ";
                dbcon.pst = dbcon.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbcon.query);
                dbcon.rs = dbcon.pst.executeQuery();
               while(dbcon.rs.next()) {
                   dbcon.results.add(new Desk_mailPojo(dbcon.rs.getInt(1), dbcon.rs.getString(2),dbcon.rs.getString(3),dbcon.rs.getDate(4), dbcon.rs.getString(5), dbcon.rs.getString(6), dbcon.rs.getString(7)));
                }
                 Iterator iter = dbcon.results.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext())
                {
                    Desk_mailPojo dmp= (Desk_mailPojo)iter.next();
                    enddate=dmp.getDate();
                    email=dmp.getEmail();
                    policyname=dmp.getPolicyname();
                    policyno=dmp.getPolicyno();
                    detailsid = dmp.getDetailsid();
                    remdays=Integer.parseInt(dmp.getRemindme());
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(enddate);
                    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -remdays);
                    String output = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
                    remdate= dateFormat.parse(output);
                    c.setTime(enddate);
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
                    expdate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
                    if(date.before(remdate)){
                         dbcon.query="-----MYSQL QUERY-----" ;
                         dbcon.pst = dbcon.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbcon.query);
                         dbcon.pst.setInt(1, detailsid);
                         dbcon.result=dbcon.pst.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    else if (((date.after(remdate))||(date.equals(remdate)))&&(date.before(enddate))){
                         dbcon.query="-----MYSQL QUERY-----" ;
                         dbcon.pst = dbcon.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbcon.query);
                         dbcon.pst.setInt(1, detailsid);
                         dbcon.result=dbcon.pst.executeUpdate();
                         if (dbcon.result>0){
                             body="The insurance policy "+policyname+"with policyno:"+policyno+" will be expired on "+ enddate;
                             m1.sendmail(body, email);
                         }
                    }
                    else if((date.after(remdate))&&(date.after(enddate))){
                         dbcon.query="-----MYSQL QUERY----- " ;
                         dbcon.pst = dbcon.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbcon.query);
                         dbcon.pst.setInt(1, detailsid);
                         dbcon.result=dbcon.pst.executeUpdate();
                          if ((dbcon.result>0)&&(date.before(expdate))){
                             body="The insurance policy "+policyname+"with policyno:"+policyno+" has been expired on "+ enddate;
                              m1.sendmail(body, email);
                          }
                     }


                }


            }catch(Exception e){

                 throw new Exception("changestatus" + e.getMessage());

            }
            return dbcon.result;
        }






        public int sendmail(String message,String email) throws Exception
        {
            try{

            Properties props =System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpServ);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");

            Authenticator auth = new Desk_mail.SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session=Session.getInstance(props,auth);


            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email, false));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(message);

            msg.setHeader("MyMail", "Mr. XYZ" );
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messagePart.setText(message);


            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);


            msg.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Message sent to"+email+" OK." );
            return 0;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   


                return -1;
            }


        }

        private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
        {
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                String username =  "mailid";           // specify your email id here (sender's email id)
                String password = "*****";                                      // specify your password here
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        }

    }
```

Also I am reading  xml . the code of that class as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;



public class readxml {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

      try {

         String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
                path=path+"/dbconfig.xml";
        File fXmlFile = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("db");
//                String username
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

                String username;
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

           Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
//                     url = getTagValue("username", eElement);
//                      driver = getTagValue("username", eElement);
//                      username = getTagValue("username", eElement);
//                       password = getTagValue("username", eElement);
//                      

                      System.out.println("URL" + getTagValue("url", eElement));
              System.out.println("driver" + getTagValue("driver", eElement));
                  System.out.println("username" + getTagValue("username", eElement));
              System.out.println("password " + getTagValue("password", eElement));

           }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
               try{

         throw new Exception("" + en.getMessage());
      }
  }

  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }

}
```

This is the response of commandline when i try to execute the jar file by using this command
:java -jar Myjarfile.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: can you give the JAVA_HOME configured?

Answer (score 0):

> Is setting the Classpath is my problem?

Basically yes.  The extra API needs to be put on a path relative to the main Jar ('same directory' works well for most apps.) & mentioned in the manifest of the main Jar file.

See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for more details.